# Inserting record using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post data using jquery for insertion but not able to do so the variables are geting values correctly but i dont think so that php page is working after that, i dont think that there is any mistake in php page.
Here is my code

```
<script>
function print_this(){

var nit =$('#a').val();
var reg = $('#b').val();
var c = $('#csa').val();
var d = $('#dc').val();
var e = $('#Ee').val();
var f = $('#Er').val();
var w = $('#w').val();
var h = $('#w').val();
var i = $('#i').val();
PostValue(a,b,c,d,e,f,w,h,i)}

function PostValue(a,b,c,d,e,f,w,h,i){
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "print.php",
data: {a:a,b:b,c:c,d:d,e:e,f:f,w:w,h:h,i:i},
success:function(data){
$("#print").printThis();
}
})
```

}

Here is my php page

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','','') or die ("Connection Problem");
mysql_select_db("") or die ("Database Problem");
function print_this(){
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];
$d = $_POST['d'];
$query = "select * from print where a = $a and b = $b and c = $c and d = $d";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
 $query = "INSERT INTO print (id ,a,b,c,d,e,f,w,h,i) VAUES 
(NULL, '".$_POST['a']."','".$_POST['b']."','".$_POST['c']."','".$_POST['d']."','".$_POST['e']."','".$_POST['f']."','".$_POST['w']."','".$_POST['h']."','".$_POST['i']."')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();}
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What goes wrong where? Output mySQL error messages using `mysql_error()` and peek e.g. in your browser's element inspector what value comes back from the Ajax call. Also make test outputs of your fields. At which point do they become empty (if at all)? Your script is also vulnerable to SQL injection, see http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type on your ajax post and stringify your JSON.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "print.php",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({a:a,b:b,c:c,d:d,e:e,f:f,w:w,h:h,i:i}),
    success: function (data) {
        $("#print").printThis();
    }
})
```

Be sure to include [JSON.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) if you are supporting older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that when you insert data to your table, you considered your data as a varchar but when you want to select you didn't put your values between single quotes, for more details add after the first mysql_query(), mysql_error() function to debug your script.